# Image becomes pixelated when game is run

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, scaling, blender, skspritenode

I have a Sprite that I made in Blender. I add it to GameScene.sks and scale it down to match the tilemap tile size. I have added a pinch gesture to my game and when I start up the game and zoom in on the Sprite the image becomes very pixelated.

Why does my image become pixelated when I zoom in? It looks good in GameScene.sks.

Here are my settings in Blender: 
Resolution: 
X: 512
Y: 1024
100%
100 Samples

I import to GIMP to autoCrop. And Scale Image to 144 px/inch. 
This gives me:
Width: 510
Height: 394

I import to my GameScene.sks as a Sprite. 
My Tiles are:
W: 64
H: 32

**Here is what it looks like in GameScene.sks when I add it.**

[image]

**This is what it looks like in the Simulator.**

[image]

My Scene is 2048X1536. 
And I am using .aspectFill in GameViewController.

I'm sure my methodology is incorrect.

All I want is for my tower to look non-pixelated when I zoom in with the pinch gesture.

Comment: What's the largest amount of your 2048x1536 screen space the tower ever takes up when zoomed in? If you want it to not pixelate, that's the size you're going to need render it out at, and import it into SpriteKit as. Without this amount of information, you're relying on SpriteKit's less than stellar upScaling abilities.

Comment: Thanks Confused! When I zoom in the image should take up 1/2 the screen of the device. When I zoom out it should be the entire scene. In GameScene.sks I shrink the image down to 64x32 to match the tile size.

Comment: So, at some point, the tower is fullscreen?

Comment: Yes. When I zoom in I want the tower to take up most of the screen. Currently when I am zoomed out i can see the entire scene. When I zoom in on one tower it looks really pixelated. I just want the tower to look nice and clear looking.

Comment: Ok. Whatever that maximum size is, that's what you have to render the tower at, in pixels. And then import to your project at that size. And turn on mipmapping so it scales down nicely.

Comment: Once you've got it working, answer your own question with examples of your renders, and the code for turning on mipMapping, so others can learn from this. I'm a 3ds Max and Vray guy, mostly. Can't get my head around Blender's UI/UX. Others will upvote your answer as it helps them, and you'll get enough points to inline images for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom in the image becomes pixelated as the dimensions are not that high so don't keep the image close to the camera, instead move it further and scale it
 more in size
Check this link https://bgetutorials.wordpress.com/2007/11/07/how-to-get-realtime-text-in-blender/ 
if this doesn't work try UV unwraping it and scalling it